# Spring Data JPA - ManyToOne unable to delete child without modifying parent list

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I struggle for a week with the following problem:

How is it possible to delete a child entity through a repository without modifying the List on the owning (parent) side of the relation?

Thanks in advance.

I am hoping for some answers!

The **child** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

And the **parent** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
         this.children = children;
    }

    public Parent addChild(Child child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Parent removeChild(Child child) {
        this.children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And here the **test**:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testParentToChildRelationShip() {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Child child = new Child();

    parent.addChild(child);
    parent.addChild(new Child());
    parent.addChild(new Child());
    parent.addChild(new Child());

    parentRepository.save(parent);

    Assertions.assertThat(parentRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1L);
    Assertions.assertThat(childRepository.count()).isEqualTo(4L);

    childRepository.delete(child);


    Assertions.assertThat(parentRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1L);
    // fails
    Assertions.assertThat(childRepository.count()).isEqualTo(3L);

    parentRepository.delete(parent.getId());

    Assertions.assertThat(parentRepository.count()).isEqualTo(0L);
    Assertions.assertThat(childRepository.count()).isEqualTo(0L);
}
```

The test would work if I insert before deleting the child,

```
child.getParent().removeChild(child);
```

but I want to avoid calling this.
Is there a way to make it work with just calling the Child-JPA-Repository.delete method? Or other annotations that I missed?

Comment: What happens if you flush() after calling childRepository.delete(child)?

Comment: It makes no difference. The child repository count still is 4. I tried flushing on the child repository, on the parent repository and on both

Comment: What happens if you populate the set from a setup method - is the txn scope different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `child` has association with `parent` you are facing this issue, you need to remove the link between child and parent either using

```
parent.removeChild(child);
```

or

```
child.getParent().removeChild(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your parent class and also setter and getter of `children`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnore
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
        private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
```

I think you can remove `child mapping` from your `parent class` so you can easily delete the child row using `ChildRepository` `delete()` method but problem is that you have to save your child `manually` using `ChildRepository` `save()`. You can not save child object with parent object using `ParentRepository`. Change your **Test** code like below for saving `child` and `parent`

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Parent parent = parentRepository.save(parent);

    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);
    childRepository.save(child);
```

Comment: Is there no other bidirectional possibility of solving this problem?

Comment: I think other solution should be that you can create a field `isDeleted` in your `child class` and not try to delete the child row just update this field `isDeleted` to `true` and at the time of getting only get the row who are `isDeleted` `false`.